# Xamarin Mac Agent Connection issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin, I am having problems connecting from my windows 10 PC to my mac mini. If I disable Windows firewall I can connect but I don't want to leave my firewall turned off. Anyone know what port needs to be opened on the windows machine for the mac agent to communicate with? I tried opening SSH (Port 22), but that didn't help.

Comment: I haven't opened any ports in my firewall to enable it to communicate with the Mac. You do however have to enable Remote Login on you Mac.

Comment: Yep I've done that, it works fine if I disable windows firewall, seems like it needs some port open on my windows machine which is a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

[Xamarin Firewall Configuration Instructions](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/firewall/)

> Xamarin Mac Agent
>
> To connect Visual Studio to your Mac build host using the Xamarin Mac Agent requires the SSH port to be open. By default this is Port 22.